# why IdentityDbContext change to DbContext whenever I update model using database first approach in asp.net core 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, ef-core-3.1

Whenever I update Model using database-first approach I have two
problems.

First one is

```
QuizVContext :IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

changes to `QuizVContext : DbContext`

I also have to write  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder) over
again and again when update model to avoid this identity error

> InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin' requires a primary key to be defined. If
> you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'.

I have commented line which got change.

```
  **//this IdentityDbContext change to Dbcontext**    
  public partial class QuizVContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
        {
            public QuizVContext()
            {
            }
            public QuizVContext(DbContextOptions<QuizVContext> options)
                : base(options)
            {
    
            }
            public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoles> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserClaims> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserLogins> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserRoles> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<MigrationHistory> MigrationHistory { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<TblClass> TblClass { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<TblCourse> TblCourse { get; set; }
    
            protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            {
                if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
                {
                   optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=xxx;Database=dd;Trusted_Connection=True;");
                }
            }
    
            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                **//this got removed on updating model I need to add manually**
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
              
                modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetRoles>(entity =>
                {
                    entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasMaxLength(128);
    
                    entity.Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired();
                });
            }
```

Comment: That's because you *replace* the existing model, not update it. This question has nothing to do with ASP.NET Core either - that's a web stack, not an ORM. You're probably using EF Core 3.1. How do you "update" the model? With `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` ? What's the exact command?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Scaffold-DbContext "Server=xxx;Database=dd;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Force

Comment: That rewrites the model. Instead of trying to 'update' the model you should create a migration

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos please tell me how can I avoid to rewrites the model?

Comment: by reading some articles I got to know there is no way to update just changes ,we have to update all entities in case of small change in model .there is another solution in which we can mention table name in scaffold command to update that table just.

Comment: You can use eg [EF Core Power Tools](https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/wiki/Reverse-Engineering#saving-options-and-running-the-second-time) to specify base classes and preserve the generation settings. You can also protect specific files from regeneration. Both `Scaffold` and the  Power Tools generate [partial classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods), which allows you to save any custom code in a separate file that won't be overwritten.

Comment: thanks I will look into that